# When should I concat Angular2 App as opposite to SystemJS approach?

Tags: angular, systemjs

When should I concat my Angular2 app, and when should I leave my SystemJS original approach (leaving different modules in different files)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It mainly depends on browser support.

The old way, pre http2, was to bundle everything into one big file. Now that we have http2 on the way, it's no longer necessary depending on what browsers and servers you target.

Please note that the server should be configured for http2 if you are serving many files, but both nginx and apache (with mod_http2) has http2 support, so you should be ok.

Browser support: ~70% according to [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=http2).

Comment: Could you expand? What does HTTP2 provide over the HTTP?

Comment: Mainly support for sending multiple files together. Http1 is limited to 1 file at once / tcp connection. https://http2.github.io/faq/#why-is-http2-multiplexed

Comment: Got ya. How about trade off between having to load very small files, over having them all bundled up together? Does it make sense to still load them (which takes time) per request?

Comment: Since everything is sent over the same connection, I'd say just count bytes (that is, if you can load them in parallel). 2 500b or 1 1000b file shouldn't matter